# "returning" an object without including it C++

Tags: c++, pointers, object, constructor

I hope this hasn't been asked too many times, i tried to search but couldn't really find anything (maybe i just didn't know how to put it in the correct terms). Simple question:

I have a class vec3 which has 3 fields x,y and z
in it theres a function flatten that i want to return a vec2 object (or something a vec2 object can be constructed from) which has only the fields x and y. Since this is the only function in vec3 class that has to do with vec2 i wouldn't want to include vec2. Is tbere any better way to return such a simple object (two doubles) without any includes?

I thought of returning a pointer but what happens if i do this:

`vec2 v2 = vec3(x,y,z).flatten(); // vec3(x,y,z) is the constructor`

Will the temporary vec3 objects x and y data still exist when v2 tries to construct from them? In this case `vec2 = double*` would be defined in vec2 class.

vec3 and vec2 look like this:

```
class vec3{
   double x,y,z;
}
```

Would x y and z be consecutive in memory? I would guess not.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need a partial declaration for a return type :

**Vec3.h :**

```
// No #include "Vec2.h" !

class vec2; // Partial declaration

class vec3 {
    //...
    vec2 flatten() const;
    //...
};
```

**Vec3.cpp :**

```
#include "Vec2.h"

vec2 vec3::flatten() const {
    //...
}
```